# How to write multiple .csv files based on responses from API that are date dependent

Tags: r

I am trying to create csv files that correspond to the response received from an API on a given date.

Instead of having to edit my code each time I want a new date, it seems logical to create a loop. I created a vector called "date", and tried to run the following code.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
date=c("201801","201802","201803","201804","201805")

for(i in 1:5){
url="https://website.com/api/data"
body=list(fields=list("symbol", "letter", "number"),
          history=date[i])
response=POST(url, body=body, encode="json")
data=content(response)$data       #data is a portion of the response#
write.csv(data[[i]], paste(i, ".csv"))
}
```

Note that if I eliminate the for loop and just use an element from the date vector, I get the output desired for one date

```
url="https://website.com/api/data"
body=list(fields=list("symbol", "letter", "number"),
          history=date[2])
response=POST(url, body=body, encode="json")
data=content(response)$data       #data is a portion of the response#
write.csv(data, '2.csv')
```

Using the for loop creates an empty response. Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: your mistake is most likely here: `data[[i]]`. Why are you subsetting it inside loop, while you are not doing it in your non-loop example?

Comment: Also it would be slightly better to wrap your non-loop version in a generic function and call it inside loop or lapply. As it would have less side effects.

Comment: I guess I am confused how I should use the 'write.csv' command for the loop, and a prior post showed that snippet as a way to use the command within a loop. Is there a better way to say "for each iteration, create a csv file  based on the data vector, and name the file the iteration number"?

Comment: you are already doing it. But there is no need to sub-set data (I am assuming as you haven't done it on your non-loop example), as data is overwritten inside loop each iteration.
So: `write.csv(data, paste0(i, ".csv"))` is equivalent to your non-loop. Everything else seems to be the same.

Comment: hmm no luck with that, although it makes logical sense to me. Still getting empty return from the API

Comment: Likely you have to wait for API response before writing to csv. Does the single version take some time to run? Add a `Sys.sleep(##)` just before `write.csv` in loop.

Comment: @Parfait great, that was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, with iterations such as `for` or `lapply` running potentially open-ended processes, consider having the loop wait for process to complete using `Sys.sleep(##)`. Also, use `seq_along` to avoid hard-coded count of the *dates* vector:

```
dates = c("201801","201802","201803","201804","201805")

for(i in seq_along(dates)){
   url = "https://website.com/api/data"
   body = list(fields = list("symbol", "letter", "number"),
               history = dates[i])
   response = POST(url, body = body, encode = "json")
   data = content(response)$data       # data is a portion of the response

   Sys.sleep(5)     # ADJUST SECONDS AS NEEDED                          
   write.csv(data, paste0(dates[i], ".csv"))
}
```

Alternatively, use `lapply` and even return the data after writing each csv into a list for use later:

```
data_list <- lapply(seq_along(dates), function(i)  {    
     url = "https://website.com/api/data"
     body = list(fields = list("symbol", "letter", "number"),
                 history = dates[i])
     response = POST(url, body = body, encode = "json")
     data = content(response)$data       # data is a portion of the response

     Sys.sleep(5)     # ADJUST SECONDS AS NEEDED                          
     write.csv(data, paste0(dates[i], ".csv"))

     return(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a bit more readable like this:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

date <- c("201801","201802","201803","201804","201805")
url <- "https://website.com/api/data"

# Define function
write_files <- function(date, i) {
  body <- list(fields = list("symbol", "letter", "number"),
               history = date)
  response <- POST(url, body = body, encode = "json")
  data <- content(response)$data
  write.csv(data, file = i)
}

# Apply function to each element of date
imap(date, write_files)
```

(your example was not reproducible so this is untested)